# Quadratic function.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality, quadratics

Let $\quad f(x)=ax^2+bx+c \quad $ be a quadratic function, $x \in \left (0,d \right )$ a domain of $f(x)$.
If I need $f(x)$ to be positive, that would be achieved for $ x \in \left (-\infty,x_{-} \right) \cup \left (x_{+}, +\infty \right)  $.
But what are the ways to check for $x_{-}$ and $x_{+}$ if they belong to the $ \left (0,d \right )$ ?

The question above is an attempt to generalize what should be a solution to a concrete problem: $$\frac{2x^2+x(8-a)-2}{2x(ax+2)}>0, \quad x\in\left (0,-\frac{2}{a} \right ),\quad a<0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{2x^2+x(8-a)-2}{2x(ax+2)}=
\frac{2 \left(x-\frac{1}{4} \left(a-8-\sqrt{(a-16) a+80}\right)\right) \left(x-\frac{1}{4} \left(a-8+\sqrt{(a-16) a+80}\right)\right)}{2x(ax+2)}
$$

Only one of the roots of the numerator belongs to the interval of interest:
$$\frac{1}{4} \left(a-8+\sqrt{(a-16) a+80}\right)
\in\left (0,-\frac{2}{a} \right ),\quad a<0$$
This holds for any $a<0$.

The inequality $$\frac{2x^2+x(8-a)-2}{2x(ax+2)}>0$$
with $a<0$ holds for 
$$\left (0,-\frac{2}{a} \right ) \ni x>\frac{1}{4} \left(a-8+\sqrt{(a-16) a+80}\right)$$

---

To show this mathematically you do as following.

Let
$$f(x)=\frac{2x^2+x(8-a)-2}{2x(ax+2)}$$
Find the extremum 
$$f'(x)= 4x+8-a$$
solve $4x+8-a=0$ for $x$, that is
$x=\frac{a-8}4$. Now the question do we have maximum or minimum here. For this we do second derivative test:
$$f''(x)=4>0$$ that is we have minimum as you need.

Next, find the roots
$$r_{\pm}(a)=\frac{1}{4} \left(a-8\pm\sqrt{(a-16) a+80}\right)
$$
Differentiate with respect to $a$ and solve $r'_{\pm}(a)=0$ you will have no roots, which means $r_{\pm}(a)$ doesn't cross x-axis, so evaluate $r_{\pm}(0)$ to see that $r_{+}(a)>0$.

In order to show it also satisfies $r_{+}(a)<-\frac{2}{a}$ do the same trick with $g(a)=r_{+}(a)+\frac{2}{a}$. That is solve $g'(a)=0$. You should find no real root, therefore all you need is evaluate it at some value of $a$ to discover that $g(a)<0$, which gives exactly what you need,i.e. $r_{+}(a)<-\frac{2}{a}$.

Comment: Kinda know all that. But am unable to strictly mathematically show that root $x_{+}$ belongs to the interval. That's what I was initially asking.

Comment: do you need a sort of prove for the later inequality?

Comment: All I need is how you concluded that this $\frac{1}{4} \left(a-8+\sqrt{(a-16) a+80}\right)
\in\left (0,-\frac{2}{a} \right )$ holds.

Comment: hold on, will take a little while

Comment: ready, sorry for a delay